# How to add JSONObject to Global JSONArray in another public class

Tags: java, android, arrays, global-variables, json

I have a problem or maybe better a dilemma. I must add a JSONObject to Global JSONArray that I later get this array from another activity. What is a better solution?

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObject.put("strefa", strefa);
                jsonObject.put("adres", adres);
                jsonObject.put("kryteria", kryteria);
                jsonObject.put("telefon", telefon);
                jsonObject.put("data", data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            GlobalConfig.JsonArray.put(jsonObject); // this is public static JSONArray JsonArray = new JSONArray();
```

or better is create a public method with a private object in GlobalConfig class?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you are asking here. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Passing data between two activities? Does it have to be Json? etc.

Comment: I need to have a Global Variable but my variable must be an array which has a JSON Objects so I need JSONArray. I must have to access to the array from each activity. First activity create JSONArray and second etc. get this a data from the array. I created this array but I don't know which method is better whether put a jsonObject to array in this way: GlobalConfig.JsonArray.put(jsonObject); or by the method which is in GlobalConfig class: public void addJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            JsonArray.put(jsonObject);

        }